# Restructure in aggregation monogdb

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Can I restructure data with mongodb's aggregation framework from

```
array: [{date: "27-08-12", nestedArray: [0, 1, 2]}, {date: "18-08-12", nestedArray: [0, 2]}]
```

to

```
array: [{"27-08-12": [0, 1, 2]}, {"18-08-12": [0, 2]}]
```

?

Comment: Depends on what you want to do with it. You want to query it, you want to update the database or? Provide more information and what you have, what you want achieved, where the result should be consumed/stored and on what conditions.

Comment: Too many variations on this theme to guess.  Please provide 2 input docs and 1 (or more if appropriate) output docs and what you have tried to get there.
Also:  Turning rvals like dates into lvals (keys) often leads to confusion and trouble later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this one?

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$unwind": "$array"
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": null,
      "data": {
        "$push": {
          k: "$array.date",
          v: "$array.nestedArray"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "array": {
        "$arrayToObject": "$data"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/o4l3ufoJyWL)

Comment: Careful; this works reliably only on a single doc.   Change to `{$group: (_id: "$_id"}}` to make it work one more than one doc if any dates are the same.   But the OP didn't make the real dataset very clear.

Comment: I know the solution is limited but the sample data does not provide more.